# Weird output observed on executing ssh commands remotely over ProxyCommand

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

Team, I have two steps to perform:

1. SCP a shell script file to remote ubuntu linux machine
2. Execute this uploaded file on remote ubuntu linux machine over SSH session using PROXYCommand because I have bastion server in front.

Code:

```
scp -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key -o "ProxyCommand ssh -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key lab@api.dev.test.com -W %h:%p"  /home/dtlu/backup/test.sh lab@$k8s_node_ip:/tmp/

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key -W %h:%p lab@api.dev.test.com' lab@$k8s_node_ip "uname -a; date;echo "Dummy123!" | sudo -S bash -c 'echo 127.0.1.1 \`hostname\` >> /etc/hosts'; cd /tmp; pwd; systemctl status cachefilesd | grep Active; ls -ltr /tmp/test.sh; echo "Dummy123!" | sudo -Sv && bash -s < test.sh"
```

Both calls above are working fine. I am able to upload `test.sh` and also its running but what is bothering me is during the process am observe weird output being thrown out.

output:

```
/tmp. <<< expected
[sudo] password for lab: Showing one                 
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a              destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a

Root directory /run/log/journal added.
Considering /run/log/journal/df22e14b1f83428292fe17f518feaebb.
Directory /run/log/journal/df22e14b1f83428292fe17f518feaebb added.
File /run/log/journal/df22e14b1f83428292fe17f518feaebb/system.journal added.
```

So, I don't want `/run/log/hournal` and other lines which don't correspond to my command in sh.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes around `Dummy123!`

Comment: Those lines seem to be the output of `test.sh`. Redirect its output to a file or `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding `-q` to the scp and ssh commands to reduce the output they might produce.  You can also redirect stderr and stdout to /dev/null as appropriate.

For example:

```
{
scp -q -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key -o "ProxyCommand ssh -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key lab@api.dev.test.com -W %h:%p"  /home/dtlu/backup/test.sh lab@$k8s_node_ip:/tmp/ 

ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -i /home/dtlu/.ssh/key.key -W %h:%p lab@api.dev.test.com' lab@$k8s_node_ip "uname -a; date;echo "Dummy123!" | sudo -S bash -c 'echo 127.0.1.1 \`hostname\` >> /etc/hosts'; cd /tmp; pwd; systemctl status cachefilesd | grep Active; ls -ltr /tmp/test.sh; echo "Dummy123!" | sudo -Sv && bash -s < test.sh"
} >&/dev/null
```